# Using Ambient Occlusion Maps in Blender Render

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have tried searching for an answer but, surprisingly, there are none. Of course you can activate AO in the viewport for help with depth but unlike normal maps or specular maps I have not seen a way to use AO maps; I don't think there's even an influence slider for it. There is one called Ambient but it isn't making a difference to my model.

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46287/adding-ambient-occlusion-to-material/46290#46290

Comment: Again, I tried Ambient but it doesn't seem to have an effect to the model's ambient occlusion.

Comment: No, it's not supposed to. Unless your light primarily comes from the "environment light", baked AO will make no difference, nor is it supposed to. Because all it is is shadows for the environment light. Reread my answer in that post, including the linked blog. That's how to "properly" use AO. Anything else is stylistically misusing it, in which case there's no right or wrong, just what looks good. Multiplying over diffuse is popular.