# How to bake AO + Diffuse into one map in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, texture-baking, baking

I have AO Map baked and a diffuse map. I combined together in cycles node editor and changed AO intensity through colorRamp.

[image: Shield]

Now I'd like to save these node settings and bake it into one. I've tried different things but I think I missed something.

What is the right wey?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you do not want to do this for AO, see [Adding Ambient Occlusion to Material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46287/adding-ambient-occlusion-to-material/46290#46290)

However, if you really want to in this case, you can just bake the diffuse channel. Since you multiplied AO into diffuse, it is now part of diffuse. So just bake that. If you don't want to also include lighting, set bake type to "diffuse" and bake only the color pass:

[image: bake panel with diffuse output selected, only color pass enabled]

(remember, however, by multiplying AO over diffuse, you are already "including lighting" as AO is lighting, not color)