# How do I combine AO with my image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes

I am totally new to compositing in Blender and I wanted to know if anyone could tell me how to combine the AO layer and the image layer in this LEGO brick scene that I made.[image]

[image]

All help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: It's an artistic choiche. Most commeon way is to multiply colors, but it dependes on your project's goals. What are they?

Comment: Thanks Carlo, I basically want the look of the bricks to be nice and real and the shadows to be realistic. Below is the link to how I set up the nodes: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/1uavn0i83pm59v8/node_setup.png?dl=0]

Comment: and this is the result: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqmehwmb4135gbl/LEGO_Stack_with_AO_03.jpg?dl=0]. I know it is personal preference, but what do you think?

Comment: If you are using cycles you don't really need Ambient Occlusion to be added. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104654/1853 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46290/1853

Comment: Use 'bake' in the 'ambient occlusion' and save the image. Now place this image in the object's material, and switch from MIX to MULTIPLY. And remember to check the ALPHA box for transparency to be applied

Comment: Thanks guys that settled it for me. I see what you mean.