# Blender Cycles Lightmap Baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, shadows, gltf

I've got a scene in Blender (simple house) where I want to bake the lightmap of certain objects (e.g. the floor). My goal is to export the whole model in the .gltf format to use it with three js. I already applied various texture maps but when it comes to baking the shadows, I'm not sure how to do this the right way. I know how to bake the actual lightmap by baking "shadows" (if that's even the right approach) but when overlaying it with the textures (I found some solutions on stackexchange) in the node editor, the result doesn't look appealing and realistic at all. Baking the "combined" texture leads me to the best result but the rendering time takes ages and I've read a lot that it's better to apply the lightmap as a seperate layer and leave the texture set as it is - but whats the best way to do that? I need to have the lightmap already implemented in the final .gltf model.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I face similar trouble, but all that I have now - the combined texture is a gives you the best image. But you also can try to bake Ambient Occlusion, and add it with a combination of Color ramp - so maybe it gives you the correct result. But I'm sure that when you convert it on a gtlf format, It's not saving as ambient occlusion "slot" for material - ambient becomes a part of a texture. You can see it clearly on [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) - on material props, and read an answer on 
[Ambient occlusion in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101234/ambient-occlusion-in-principled-bsdf)