# Why node wrangler doesn't recognize AO maps when using auto setup shortcut

Tags: texturing, add-on

When i used auto setup shortcut on PBR maps using Node wrangler on blender 2.8, the addon never adds AO maps but everything else is displayed and connected properly. any reason for this?

Comment: source of textures? post the link pls

Comment: i mainly use texture.com

Comment: citing @JtheNinja:
While we're discussing AO, I should probably point out a pretty common misconception when using Cycles. Cycles does not NEED actual AO for anything, ever. Cycles does not have a true ambient light..

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46287/adding-ambient-occlusion-to-material/46290#46290